# How to mount dd image of digital ocean?

Tags: image, dd

I have created a `dd` image of /`dev/vda` using the following command:

> ssh root@1.2.3.4 "dd if=/dev/vda" | dd of=/home/backup/vda.img

and I can't mount it on my local Ubuntu server where I transferred it.

I get this in `dmesg | tail` :

```
[763158.222159] EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_map_blocks:504: inode #8:block 10541546: comm mount: lblock 23018 mapped to illegal pblock (length 1)
[763158.222299] jbd2_journal_bmap: journal block not found at offset 23018 on loop0-8
[763158.222367] JBD2: bad block at offset 23018
[763158.222581] JBD2: recovery failed
[763158.222588] EXT4-fs (loop0): error loading journal
```

If I try to check it out with `file` I get:

> vda.img: data

Any idea what it could be?

Using kpartx as Sven suggested I get:

> kpartx -l /home/backup/vda.img
>   loop deleted : /dev/loop0

I have rebooted the system and tried the command again:

> kpartx -lv /home/backup/vda.img
>   ioctl: LOOP_CLR_FD: Device or resource busy
>   can't del loop : /dev/loop0

And in dmesg | tail i get

> [   73.445903] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
>   [   73.446574] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com

Comment: It is a funny thing if we learn to use hexedit... checking the actual bytes of a disk is very useful is similar situations.

Comment: Exactly how did you create this image?

Comment: @MichaelHampton add the command in the question

Comment: @Debrian: `dd`ing a live disk is very unlikely to result in anything useful, this only works reliable on unmounted (or at the very least ro-mounted) disks.

Comment: @Sven How would you suggest to do such an image on a Digital Ocean droplet then ?

Comment: No clue, don't know Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue in the following way:

I checked the size of the partition that i wished to copy and then i created a local file with that size on the backup server and created the partition inside it using the following commands:

> fallocate -l 85899345920 vda.img
>   fdisk -H 16 vda.img
>   kpartx -a vda.img
>   mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mnt/test/ -t ext4

Then i used dd to copy the data from the server to the backup partition.

Checked everything around and all seems fine.

Answer (score 6):

You likely need to mount partitions inside the image file. This can be done with `kpartx`.

```
kpartx -l /path/to/image
```

will list partitions inside the file and

```
kpartx -a /path/to/image
```

will add them to `/dev/mapper/loopXpY` (where `X` and `Y` varies), from where you can mount them with `mount`.

See `man kpartx` for more info.

Comment: I get the following output when i try to list them: kpartx -l /home/backup/vda.img 
loop deleted : /dev/loop0

Comment: @Debrian: Edit any output into your question, don't post it as comment.